# Graph: Filter calendar events by schema property

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I have this schema extension:

```
 {
    "id": "intnovaction_Docu2EventMetadata",
    "description": "Eventos de Docu2",
    "targetTypes": [
        "event"
    ],
    "status": "Available",
    "owner": "d1aaf0fa-549f-4692-8929-22eb90b33099",
    "properties": [
        {
            "name": "ActuacionId",
            "type": "String"
        },
        {
            "name": "ExpedienteId",
            "type": "String"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am able to extend **event** properties using this schema. I can set values for 'ActuacionId' and 'ExpedienteId' on an event and I can get these values through this request: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$select=id,intnovaction_Docu2EventMetadata`

that returns

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('6d418063-df8b-4f47-921b-1072baf4a949')/events(id,intnovaction_Docu2EventMetadata)",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"FwgXoe8hSUuEcCnxk8/heAAALdjYcQ==\"",
            "id": "AAMkAGE1MDUwMDZkLWRmZDctNGMxMi1hN2ZiLTUwNTBlYTc1NmRkYwBGAAAAAABIbknKwqd9SI8d_mLMOg2XBwAXCBeh7yFJS4RwKfGTz_F4AAAAAAENAAAXCBeh7yFJS4RwKfGTz_F4AAAtI8LHAAA=",
            "intnovaction_Docu2EventMetadata": {
                "ActuacionId": "1",
                "ExpedienteId": "2"
            }
        }
}
```

the problem comes when I try to filter for those properties:

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$select=id,intnovaction_Docu2EventMetadata&$filter=intnovaction_Docu2EventMetadata/ActuacionId eq '1'
```

Then I am receiving this error response

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "RequestBroker-ParseUri",
        "message": "Could not find a property named 'e2_3be22c6901b942889d07616b14e79402_intnovaction_Docu2EventMetadata' on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Event'.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "4137b6f4-1c8d-4c1e-84fd-02e8ccaab860",
            "date": "2017-10-02T19:25:28"
        }
    }
}
```

Is it not possible to filter events by schema properties?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like we missed something in our documentation. It's not currently possible to filter on schema extensions defined on Outlook based entity types (events, messages and personal contacts).  We could also improve our error messages to make this more clear too.  I'll file some items for this.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Is filtering events by schema extension property implemented now?

Comment: I don't think think this is possible - but the docs should say one way or another